# If we use the C prefix for classes, should we use it for struct also?

Tags: c++, coding-style

*Assuming that a project has been using the C class prefix for a long time, and it would be a waste of time to change at a late stage, and that the person who originally wrote the style guide has been hit by a bus, and that there are no structs in the code already...*

It's a pretty trivial question, but if a C++ code style guide says "use C for class name prefix" then should this be taken to mean also use C for struct prefix also, or should we use something different, like S for example.

```
class CFoo { };
struct CBar { };
```

... or ...

```
class CFoo { };
struct Bar { };
```

Comment: We dunno... ask your team what they meant.

Comment: Well, the initial person who wrote the style guideline has been hit by a bus (I will update my answer).

Comment: If this is an old project, what style is used for the existing structs?

Comment: Interestingly, there are no structs. Which is admittedly weird.

Comment: Perhaps structs are prohibited?

Comment: Don't you mean a CBus?  Or was it an SBus?  Your IQuestion is too hard to read() without any APrefixes!

Comment: I've see the S prefix used at my firm for structs.

Comment: As a side note, C++ would let you declare something as `struct Foo {};`, but then refer to it as `class Foo* p`. With that in mind, I don't see why Hungarian prefixes should be treated any differently.

Comment: I really hate this style concept, as it seems to be proliferated by Microsoft and those people unwilling to do something different.  One might ask the real question, "Does the type of the object, class or structure matter?" "Can one create object stencils without using class, struct or union?"  I prefer to name the classes based on theme, such as "Shape" or "Circle" instead of "CShape" and "CCircle".  "That is just my opinion, I could be wrong."

Comment: Haha, I like the destiny that the person who originally wrote the style guide has been hit by a bus.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the style guide doesn't specify, I would (probably) use the "structs are classes with all members public"-rule to use C for structs too, yes. Or I would think "hah, here's a loophope to get around that silly initial rule, yay" and not use it. In other words, this is highly subjective.

Answer (score 28):

Simple answer - don't use the C prefix for classes. This is hungarian notation of the most pointless sort. It's probably time to re-write the style guide. Frankly (and speaking as someone who's written several of the things), most such guides are rubbish and/or were written long, long ago and never updated.

Comment: Given the fact that the question is about the consistency of the style guide, basically you say that you don't have an answer...

Comment: The notation is pretty pointless, I agree, but that was not the question, as xtofl said. The question was if it has been used for classes, then should it be used for structs?

Comment: @Nick OK, the guide, if it is any good at all, should explain WHY the C prefix is being used for classes. If the same reasoning applies to structs, then use an S.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment, but this is more of a comment than an answer to the question.

Comment: @Nick I suspect it was copied blindly from Microsoft's original (and unwritten) MFC standards.

Comment: @Niel, oops, deleted my comment. But thanks for replying. This sounds logical to me.

Comment: I think this answer is right, don't spend time on problems of your own making when you can remove them. The C prefix is just about made worthwhile in Symbian, which uses C for "proper classes", T for value types, R for handles to kernel objects, and M for mixins. But I don't miss it in other C++ projects, and adding C to every single user-defined type tells you nothing. C++'s syntax makes it hard to always know what's a type and what isn't, but not that hard.

Answer (score 5):

If the code style guide doesn't specify, find code that's been following the style guide and see what's already been done.

If there is no code already following the style guide, come to an agreement with everyone involved in the project.

If nobody else is involved in the project, just decide and be consistent.

Answer (score 3):

I think this guideline is stupid and confusing.. The fact that you had to ask this question proves it.

Coding styles are meant to increase readability; it's obvious if an identifier is a class or not, especially if you are using a decent IDE with mouseover tooltips.

Comment: This kind of style guide indeed stems from the pre-ide era.  That doesn't make it useless.

Comment: Well, refusing to use an IDE for some reason and then resort to these workarounds is shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: Style guides, really, have nothing to do with IDEs.  As others have stated, the guides should be for readability and consistency.  They also help in code reviews (at a bare minimum to flame people who don't follow them).

Answer (score 2):

We usually use C prefix for classes and T prefix for structs that have no methods (ie, "C" structs).

Comment: Same here.              (-padding to meet 15 characters limit-)

Comment: And if a method is inserted into the structure or class, the name must be changed (to meet the guideline) and all the code reviewed to propagate the name change.  Primary vote against Hungarian and similar styles.

Answer (score 2):

For me it would come down to:

Do you want the readers of your code to immediately differentiate between the two declaration types?

While the use of the prefix is generally distasteful, carefully consider the view of the code maintainer.  Is it helpful for them to think, "Ah! no C prefix, this is a struct".  Using a struct instead of a class may imply something specific in your code.  If it doesn't, it makes more sense to continue to use the prefix for the sake of the maintainer.

Answer (score 2):

If a style guide does not serve its purpose to promote easy readability, consistency, and correctness, it should be modified until it does so or thrown into the circular file (trash can).

Also, if people don't follow it, then it should be updated so that it is easier to follow (or the tools amended to make coding to the guidline easier).

Answer (score 0):

According to the existing pattern of prefixing C for classes, you should prefix S for struct, I for interface.

In addition, prefix E for enum, D for delegate, D for directory, F/M for function/method, F for file, F for field, N for namespace, P for page, P for parameter, P for property, R for return value, v for variable.

As of variables, prefix

- a for array
- b for boolean
- c for char
- f for float
- g for GUID
- h for handle
- i for int
- j for json
- k for key
- l for list
- m for MarshalByRefObject
- n for Nullable
- o for object
- p for pointer
- q for queue
- r for Registry
- s for single
- t for TimeZone
- u for Uri
- v for version
- w for WeakReference
- x for XmlDocument
- y for yoda
- z for ZipFile

Example

Good:

```
namespace NGqqnbig.NConsoleApplication1
{
    class CProgram
    {
        static void Main(string[] pasArgs)
        {
            FMain(pasArgs);
        }

        static void FMain(string[] pasArgs)
        {
            var vsLine= CConsole.FReadLine();
            var viSVN= CConvert.FToInt32(vsLine);

            var occCVC = new CCCCVC();
            occCVC.PICVC = viSVN;
        }
    }

    class CCCCVC
    {
        private int fiCVC;

        public int PICVC
        {
            get { return fiCVC; }
            set { fiCVC = pivalue; }
        }
    }
}
```

Bad:

```
namespace Gqqnbig.ConsoleApplication1
{
    class CProgram
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var line= Console.ReadLine();
            var svn= Convert.ToInt32(line);

            var cardVerificationCode = new CreditCardVerificationCode();
            cardVerificationCode.VerificationCode = svn;
        }
    }

    class CreditCardVerificationCode
    {
        public int VerificationCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```